# Minimal $\ell_\infty$ solution of underdetermined system of linear equations

Tags: convex-optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming, python, cvxpy

[ **Update:** question solved, answer is at the end of the post]

---

I need to solve this problem

$$ \min \| x \|_{\infty} \; \text{s.t.} \; Ax = b $$

where $Ax = b$ is an underdetermined system, e.g., $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, with $n < m$. Unfortunately this problem seems to be not so treated in the research literature. After some googling, I found this [thesis by Earle AC](http://wiredspace.wits.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10539/16858/20140910_Infinity%2020Norm%20Minimization_MSc%20Thesis_EarleAC.pdf?sequence=1) to be a clear reference.
Many approaches are provided, unfortunately with no code at all, and the most pragmatic way to solve such a problem would be to cast this problem as a linear programming one, i.e.,

$$\min c^T [x |s] \\ A x = b \; , \; x_i \leq s , \; -x_i \leq s\\ $$
where $s$ is meant to be $\| x \|_{\infty}$, $c = [\textbf{0}|1]$, $\textbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ being the zero vector.

Such an approach is well described in page 36 of [thesis by Earle AC](http://wiredspace.wits.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10539/16858/20140910_Infinity%2020Norm%20Minimization_MSc%20Thesis_EarleAC.pdf?sequence=1)

Unfortunately when I try to code this in Python, I obtain not feasible solutions: in particular when using the simplex method of Scipy, at some point in the tableau reduction the algorithm is no more able to find a pivot in the column.

An example is provided at the end of the post.

The **questions** hence are:

1. Are there any errors in the code below? Or the problem is effectively ill posed?
2. Are there any out of the box implemented solvers that deal with the same problem?

Thanks!

```
# divergence of linear programming for minimization of l_inf norm
# for overdetermined linear solution
import numpy as np

# p.36 of Infinity Norm Minimization EarleAC
n, m = 2,5
np.random.seed(10)
b = np.random.rand(n)
A = np.random.rand(n*m).reshape((n,m))
m = A.shape[1]

# check that system has solution
if (np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.column_stack((A,b))) - np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)):
    raise ValueError("matrix rank problem")

# matrix costraints for equality Ax = b
A_eq = np.column_stack((A, np.zeros(n)))
b_eq = b

# matrix constraint for |x|<s
M_3 = np.column_stack((np.diag(np.ones(m)),  np.ones(m)))
b_3 = np.zeros(m)

M_4 = np.column_stack(( - np.diag(np.ones(m)),  np.ones(m)))
b_4 = np.zeros(m)
# contraint s > 0
M_5 = np.zeros(M_4.shape[1])
M_5[-1] = 1
b_5 = [0.]

A_ub = np.row_stack((M_3, M_4, M_5))
b_ub = np.concatenate((b_3, b_4, b_5))

# define target
from scipy.optimize import linprog
c = np.append(np.zeros(m), [1.])

sol_scipy = linprog(c = c,
        A_ub = -A_ub, # minus is to consider <= instead of >=
        b_ub = -b_ub, # minus is to consider <= instead of >=
        A_eq = A_eq,
        b_eq = b_eq,
        method =  'simplex'
        )
print sol_scipy["message"]
# >> Optimization failed. Unable to find a feasible starting point.

# however a feasible solution exists, given by

x_fea, residuals, rank, __ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)
inf_norm_fea = np.max(np.abs(x_fea))
tmp_sol = np.concatenate((x_fea, [inf_norm_fea]))

np.testing.assert_allclose(A_eq.dot(tmp_sol), b_eq)
assert np.all(A_ub.dot(tmp_sol) >= b_ub)
```

[UPDATE]

Thanks to the suggestion by Michael Grant, solving the problem with `cvxpy` (readily available out of the box through `conda install -c omnia cvxpy`) solved the problem in a straightforward manner. Thanks a lot to him (and its amazing job with cvx) and at jjjjjj for suggesting other options. Here is the code that solves the above problem.

```
import cvxpy as cvx
# Construct the problem.
x = cvx.Variable(c.shape[0])
objective = cvx.Minimize(c * x)
constraints = [A_eq*x == b_eq, A_ub*x >= b_ub ]
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)

# The optimal objective is returned by prob.solve().
result = prob.solve()
# The optimal value for x is stored in x.value.
print x.value
```

Comment: My recommendation is that you consider a tool like [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/) (disclaimer: developed by colleagues of mine). This will let you specify the problem in its native form, and let _it_ create the LP reformulation and call the underlying solver for you.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, cvxpy solved my problem. Thanks for your amazing job with cvx and the work of your friends that made the utilisation of the package astonishingly easy !

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelGrant said, you might first try using CVX on test problems to guage the feasibility concern you're seeing. Then increase the scale for your problem of interest.

If scale becomes an issue, I'd maybe consider using [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt), or if you want to build your own KKT solver, using [Pardiso](https://pardiso-project.org/) to solve the KKT system. Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with either and have been using the numerically focused [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl) which has led me to learn about IPOPT etc...

Comment: Those are great recommendations, but given that he's already in Python, cvxpy is likely the best choice.

Comment: Definitely agree!